# Sincronizar PasswordTexField con TextField para visualizar la contraseña usando un evento de tecla en JavaFX

Tags: javafx

Estoy creando un acceso Login y Password y con un checkBox quiero dar al usuario la opción de visualizar la contraseña. He superpuesto un PasswordTexField con un TextField y a ambos les he añadido a través de SceneBuilder un Evento de tecla, concretamente, `onKeyPressed`:

```
 @FXML
    void onKey_SincronizarEscritura(KeyEvent event) {
        txtContraOculta.setText(txtContraVisible.getText());
    }

    @FXML
    void onKey_SincronizarEscritura_O(KeyEvent event) {
        txtContraVisible.setText(txtContraOculta.getText());
    }
```

El problema es que al visibilizar la contraseña me añade todos los caracteres salvo el último. No logro entender eso. Sin embargo, si controlo desde el checkBox entonces sí funciona. ¿Podría alguien explicarme por qué no me añade el último caracter escrito? Además si solo escribo un caracter no lleva a cabo la sincronización.

Comment: Lo que pasa es que con KeyPressed estás llamando el evento inmediatamente después de presionar la tecla, es decir el evento no recoge el último caracter ingresado porque ese es el que lo dispara, por eso cuando sólo escribes uno no funciona la sincronización, además que no me parece correcta esta forma de manejar esto, lo más óptimo sería el checkbox o un radio button y que cuando se seleccione coja el texto de del password field, lo pase al textfield normal y haces invisible el password field y visible el otro, como están superpuestos no se va a notar que son 2 campos distintos

Comment: Exacto, si uso el CheckBox entonces la sincronización es perfecta. Gracias